# How to install Mason for Perl in Windows?

Tags: perl, apache, mason

I  want to run Mason on my Windows system . I have Active Perl 5.16  and Apache 2.2 in  my system. Perl programs are working fine and I am able to run Perl CGI Script on Apache as well. 
But I am a beginner to Mason and want to run a simple program using Mason Framework so that I can  begin learning it.

Comment: Why are you shouting (I've edited your capitalisation)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i wasn't shouting . . its all for camelCase habit . . Anyways i have configured apache to run cgi scripts and i can  create perl programs on my system  . But i dont have any clue to how to run mason in windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mason has a large number of dependency modules, but this and all of the dependencies can be installed from the command line using the cpan installer (I just verified this would work on Windows 7), though cpanm (yes, "cpanm", not a typo) seem to be the preferred install method mentioned in the module documentation. See install section of docs on CPAN (http://metacpan.org/pod/Mason).

Also, since you may be running CPAN on Windows, be aware that some modules may not compile correctly using CPAN and it may be necessary to alternate between the CPAN and ActiveState PPM module installers to get some of the dependency modules installed before Mason can be installed.